# Java UnsatisfiedLinkError when using ScalaPy: Unable to load library 'python3'

Tags: python-3.x, scala

I'm new to **Scalapy**, I'm trying to run Python code in scala using **shadaj** library, for this I have followed the official documentation [Getting Started with ScalaPy](https://scalapy.dev/docs/)

**Firstly** I have add lib dependency and define python object in build.sbt

build.sbt

```
import ai.kien.python.Python

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.1"


fork := true

lazy val python = Python("/usr/bin/python3")

lazy val javaOpts = python.scalapyProperties.get.map {
  case (k, v) => s"""-D$k=$v"""
}.toSeq

javaOptions ++= javaOpts

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "me.shadaj" %% "scalapy-core" % "0.5.2")

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "pensel"
  )
```

**Secondly**  I have add the lib dependency in plugins.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "ai.kien" %% "python-native-libs" % "0.2.2"
```

**Finally** I have wrote a small piece of code for testing purpose

```
import me.shadaj.scalapy.py
object ScalaPyPractice extends App {
    val math = py.module("math")
    val result = math.sqrt(25.0)

  println(result)

}
```

But I got an **Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'python3':
libpython3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
libpython3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

-> What I tried to set the environmental variable using terminal by running the command

```
~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin/python3

~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/bin/python3
```

but still getting the same exception `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and changed:

> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   "me.shadaj" %% "scalapy-core" %
> "0.5.2")

to

> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(          "dev.scalapy" %% "scalapy-core" %
> "0.5.3")

Problem solved